Chart.js: Is there a way to have a chart with fixed height and variable width based on the number legend's items
I would like to know if there is a way to make the chart's width increase if the number of items in the legend doesn't fit with its initial size
I tried a lot of different settings and approces like changing style attributes on container but none of them could solve my problem.
I use Chart.js v3.8.1
I prepared a codepen to help me explain the request:
Codepen
<div class="container">
    <div class="chart-container">
        <canvas style="height: 300px; width: 100%"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    display: flex;
}

.chart-container {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: fit-content;
    margin: auto 0;
    width: fit-content;
}

canvas {
    border: 2px solid green;
}


$(document).ready(() => {
    let preparedData = prepareData(60);
    const config = {
        type: "doughnut",
        data: preparedData,
        options: {
            responsive: false,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: "right"
                }
            }
        }
    };

    let chart = new Chart($("canvas"), config);
});

function prepareData(numData) {
    let labels = [];
    let localData = [];

    for (idx = 0; idx < numData; idx++) {
        labels.push("Data " + idx);
        let random = getRandomInt(100);
        localData.push(random);
    }

    let datasets = [
        {
            label: "Info",
            data: localData,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    ];

    return { labels, datasets };
}

function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}



Your codepen uses the latest version of chart.js, not 3.8.1; using an old version of the library makes it unlikely for an answer to be useful for other users, and in consequence it makes it less likely for someone to allocate the time required to write the code for a solution.

like you suggested, i changed the imported version of Chart js to the correct release, but unluckily it didn't solve the problem

On the contrary, I suggested you change, if possible, the version you are using and the text of the question to the latest version of chart.js which will increase the chances that someone will write the code to solve your problem :)

If i understand correctly, you want to show all legend labels in the chart, right?.
You can set more height to the canvas, so all legend items can fit in the size of the chart, because in pie and donut charts the aspect ratio by default is 1. (try for example height 500px instead of 300px in the canvas element). You can do a function that calculates the best height based on the number of items.
You can change also the "aspectRatio" in the options of the chart and you will get the same result, but you need to not set the height and i am not totally sure about this solution.
Another solution is to hide the legend using the chartjs options, and build the legend on the outside in html that meets your styling requirements and thus shows all elements.

I cannot change the chart's height and using a fixed value make the aspectRatio setting ignored ( as indicated in the documentation )

Yes, this two solutions are independent of each other, you can not do it at the same time. Is there a specific reason why you can't change the height of the chart, or why you can't specify it to change the aspectRatio? I think using chartjs there is not other way to achieve what you want. Maybe other solution is to simply hide the chartjs legend via options and do it by yourself in html the legend thats fits your requirements and show all the items. I will update my answer so everyone can see it.

I can't change the height because the chart would become aesthetically terrible, especially considering that i don't know exactly how much height I need to fit the entire legend.
Recreate the legend in html is also an option that i already took into consideration and, for now, seems the only valid alternative to a native solution

You can adjust the width dynamically by following these steps:


// Set the number of data points
const numData = 60;
let preparedData = prepareData(numData);

// Calculate the extra width based on the number of data points
// In this example, we add 15px for each additional data point
const extraWidthPerItem = 15;
const extraWidth = numData * extraWidthPerItem;

// Set the base width of the canvas
const baseWidth = 400;

// Calculate the total width by adding the extra width to the base width
const totalWidth = baseWidth + extraWidth;

// Apply the total width to the canvas element
const canvas = $("canvas");
canvas.attr("width", totalWidth);




Hi Juan, thanks for the answer, i thought to do that too but i was hoping to find a more flexible solution that doesn't use fixed pixel lengths because the length of the single labels is also very variable

ReferenceError: prepareData is not defined. This looks like a GPT answer. Can you make the example properly runnable and provide an explanation? Thanks.
